# gstreamer config errors Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, gstreamer

I am trying to build gstreamer but when running configure I get the following errors:

```
checking for libv4l-plugin.h... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for GST... no
configure: error: Package requirements (gstreamer-video-1.0 >= 1.4 gstreamer-app-1.0
        gstreamer-allocators-1.0) were not met:
Requested 'gstreamer-video-1.0 >= 1.4' but version of GStreamer Video Library is 1.2.4
Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.
Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GST_CFLAGS
and GST_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I have installed the packages below as I have read on other threads that would solve the problem but the issue remains the same.

*

> Reading package lists...
>    Done Building dependency tree
>    Reading state information... Done 
>    gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly is already the newest version.
>    gstreamer1.0-doc is already the newest version.
>   gstreamer1.0-plugins-base is already the newest version.
>   gstreamer1.0-plugins-good is already the newest version.
>   gstreamer1.0-tools is already the newest version. libgstreamer1.0-0 is
>   already the newest version. gstreamer1.0-libav is already the newest
>   version. gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad is already the newest version. 0
>   upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.

- I have also installed gstreamer1.4 and changed the PKG_CONFIG_PATH accordingly but it didn't helped.

  Does anybody have experience with this issue?

Thanks,

Mihaita

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install `libgstreame0.10-dev` and `libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev` library, and this is what is causing the issue. Since you are running Ubuntu, try the following command to install gstreamer :

```
apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools
```

Do not use GStreamer 0.10 version, it is not being currently maintained. You should use the GStreamer 1.0 version for your development activities.

Comment: I have already installed the 1.0 packages but the issue is not solved

Comment: try removing the `Gstreamer0.10` packages and install only the `GStreamer1.0`. I see that you replaced your earlier GStreamer 0.10 installation commands with new error messages. This might give an impression of incorrect answer.

Comment: I did removed gstreamer0.10 and let only gstreamer1.0 but the issue is the same. After your first comment i realized I did not paste the actual command (I have run the one for 1.0 package version) and edited the first post. Perhaps that was not the best way to do it from my side.